# how to dismiss the login dialog when using Facebook SDK in Unity for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm integrating facebookSDK into my unity project for log-in, but apart from clicking on the (X) on the dialog, I've got no way in script to close/dismiss the log in dialog.

Is this doable?